# Hibernate Optimistic Lock Issue

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to fix an hibernate optimistic lock exception. I can recreate the problem and can fix the issue using a session clear however I am reluctant to use clear as it will clear other queries in progress by other threads and other cached tables. I am looking for a way to refresh only table with the issue. There is a session refresh method but that seams to only refresh one entity in the table were I want to refresh the entire table. Is there a way to refresh the complete table ? Thanks.

Comment: **I am reluctant to use clear as it will clear other queries in progress by other threads** Sessions are meant to be used in single threaded env and rather not shared - so you are doing wrong there.

Comment: Is the safest thing to call flush before clear ?